# Why 1 out of 4 images isn't pushed into ECR

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I could really learn some debugging techniques related to when images fail to be pushed into ECR on AWS.

I've got this "pusher" script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail

if [ -z "$GITLAB_PULL_REQUEST" ] || [ "$GITLAB_PULL_REQUEST" == "false" ]
then

  if [[ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "staging" ]]; then
    export DOCKER_ENV=stage
  elif [[ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "production" ]]; then
    export DOCKER_ENV=prod
  fi

  if [ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "staging" ] || \
     [ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "production" ]
  then
    curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
    unzip awscli-bundle.zip
    ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
    export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
    export AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=27472596600
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAJGN7TUVKNORFB2A
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=M8GZei4Bf8aAWpcml1l7vzyedec8FkLWAYBSC7K
    eval $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-2 --no-include-email)
    export TAG=$GITLAB_BRANCH
    export REPO=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
  fi

  if [ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "staging" ] || \
     [ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "production" ]
  then
    docker build $USERS_REPO -t $USERS:$COMMIT -f Dockerfile-$DOCKER_ENV
    docker tag $USERS:$COMMIT $REPO/$USERS:$TAG
    docker push $REPO/$USERS:$TAG  # SUCCESSFULLY PUSHED

    docker build $USERS_DB_REPO -t $USERS_DB:$COMMIT -f Dockerfile
    docker tag $USERS_DB:$COMMIT $REPO/$USERS_DB:$TAG
    docker push $REPO/$USERS_DB:$TAG  # SUCCESSFULLY PUSHED

    docker build $SWAGGER_REPO -t $SWAGGER:$COMMIT -f Dockerfile-$DOCKER_ENV
    docker tag $SWAGGER:$COMMIT $REPO/$SWAGGER:$TAG
    docker push $REPO/$SWAGGER:$TAG  # SUCCESSFULLY PUSHED

    docker build $CLIENT_REPO -t $CLIENT:$COMMIT -f Dockerfile-prod --build-arg REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=""
    docker tag $CLIENT:$COMMIT $REPO/$CLIENT:$TAG
    docker push $REPO/$CLIENT:$TAG  # LEFT OUT
  fi
fi
```

Don't worry about the creds. They're not valid. I'm using GitLab CI and I can see no errors in the job log.

this is the job log of the image push:

```
Step 1/20 : FROM node:11.12.0-alpine as builder
  ---> 09084e4ff58d
 Step 2/20 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 7ee698668926
 Step 3/20 : RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python make g++
  ---> Using cache
  ---> a9f861b8e62f
 Step 4/20 : ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 5c3b377be213
 Step 5/20 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
  ---> 3a102c4e6b87
 Step 6/20 : COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
  ---> a92e6e57548b
 Step 7/20 : RUN npm install --no-optional
  ---> Running in f62c36ac767e
 > cypress@4.1.0 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/cypress
 > node index.js --exec install
 Installing Cypress (version: 4.1.0)
 [10:33:58]  Downloading Cypress     [started]
 [10:33:59]  Downloading Cypress      0% 0s [title changed]
 [10:33:59]  Downloading Cypress      1% 10s [title changed]
 [10:33:59]  Downloading Cypress      3% 7s [title changed]
 [10:33:59]  ...
             ...
 [10:34:16]  Unzipping Cypress        9% 149s [title changed]
 [10:34:18]  Unzipping Cypress        9% 172s [title changed]
 [10:34:18]  Unzipping Cypress        100% 0s [title changed]
 [10:34:18]  Unzipped Cypress        [title changed]
 [10:34:18]  Unzipped Cypress        [completed]
 [10:34:18]  Finishing Installation  [started]
 [10:34:18]  Finished Installation   /root/.cache/Cypress/4.1.0 [title changed]
 [10:34:18]  Finished Installation   /root/.cache/Cypress/4.1.0 [completed]
 You can now open Cypress by running: node_modules/.bin/cypress open
 https://on.cypress.io/installing-cypress
 added 2034 packages from 768 contributors and audited 38602 packages in 78.928s
 found 1073 vulnerabilities (1058 low, 14 moderate, 1 high)
   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Saving cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:01
 Job succeeded
```

What debugging techniques I can use here ? Please ask if there's anything you need to know.

Comment: Can you push last one is 3 others are commented out? Which messages do you get?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. The comments indicate which images are pushed into ECR and which one isn't. The last one isn't but I get no error output so I don't know how to go about debugging it.

Comment: Can you push images separately? Does it wotk if you remove all other uploads except last one from the script? Maybe try writing last upload outside of script, directly from command line without var placeholders. Also, you may add "set -ex" at the beginning of your script to ensure the commands are what you expect and no failures are silent.

Comment: Yes, all 3 images before the client image are pushed. Strangely, if I move the client image on top to make it build first no images are pushed. I'm installing GitLab locally hopefully will give some insight into what's happening because as of now I'm left blind to what's happening.

Answer (score -1):

It happens for us as well. Seems like a concurrency problem